# Hide client IP using NGINX proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

trying to access a remote resource that has a block on  some country IP addresses . I therefore thought of using NGINX as a proxy to hide the IP address of the browser and request the resource by showing a different IP address. My configuration seems not works  the remote resource blocks access by somehow identifying the browser's address.

```
set_real_ip_from 176.9.0.1/24;  #  nginx server ip range
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;

location /test/ {
    rewrite ^\/test\/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass  https://remote.blocked.biz;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host         remote.blocked.biz   ;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. the remote resource recognizes that the browser ip belongs to a non-enabled country

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @MaxStainer?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue recently, what I am doing like this:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  balabala.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /root/.acme.sh/balabala.example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/.acme.sh/balabala.example.com_ecc/reddwarf.life.key;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 1m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        set_real_ip_from 92.210.23.237;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 92.210.23.237;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

then using this Python code on the backend to get the real ip(check the ip replace success):

```
@router.get("/v1/stream")
def do_stream(q: str, authorization: str = Header(None), request: Request = None):
    client_host = request.client.host
```

you will found the real ip was replaced.